# Css after pusedo display before the div

Tags: html, css

Im trying to do simple arrow with css and when im using after, the element is display before the div. why this is happening?

```
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 3em;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7B98B5;
}

    <div></div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/SkUY5ygufCdXXpRdSQl5?p=preview

Comment: You have no content in the div to push the arrow over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make sure to include:

```
div {
    ...
    position: relative;
}
div:after {
    ....
    position: absolute;
    left: 100%;
}
```

Updated your Plunker (never heard of that site before): http://plnkr.co/edit/7oXVgqEBLBuoYLDsRlEM?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You still need to position the element properly. I would do something like this:

```
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 3em;
  position: relative; /* Added */
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute; /* Added */
  right: -40px; /* Added */
  top: 0; /* Added */
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7B98B5;
}
```

Comment: I'd personally do `left: 100%` instead of `right: -x` so the element will be width-agnostic.

Comment: @philtune, true enough. Both will do the trick. I do like your solution a bit better ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `float: right` to pseudo-element `:after`:

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 3em;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7B98B5;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

A pseudo element becomes a child of the applied element. So, making it `:after`, won't put it after the element itself, but after the element's content... which it is in fact doing.

Since you have no content, it appears to be at the left of the div, but it is not...

```css
div {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #000;
  margin-top: 3em;
  color:white;
}
div:after {
  content: '';
  display:inline-block;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 20px 0 20px 40px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #7B98B5;
}
```

```html
<div>my div content</div>
```